# AWS SSM reverse tunnel to AWS ECS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-ssm

For development and debug I would like to **run a NodeJS app on my laptop** and make it **available as a task running on ECS Fargate**.

I did accomplish that working with laptop and an EC2 instance (without ECS) by **reverse forwarding my local NodeJS app port to the EC2 80 port**, so that my local NodeJS app was available to `http://<EC2_PUBLIC_IP>` . As such, any http call to that address was actually served by local laptop, and therefore I could debug with my IDE as usual.

I am wondering if there is a way to reverse forward to Fargate too by SSM.